# if i want to free some space on my Dev machine can i shrink the WSS Logging database

Tags: 2013, administration, database, sql, farm

I am working on my Dev machine, and i am running out of space, now i check the WSS Logging database and i find that it have 34% of its size as a free space :-

[image]

so are there any harm if i shrink it ? now i check my SPUsageDefinition , and i set their retension to be one day only:-

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>  Get-SPUsageDefinition

Name                                          Retention  Enabled
----                                          ---------  -------
Analytics Usage                               1          True
App Monitoring                                1          True
App Statistics.                               1          True
Bandwidth Monitoring                          1          False
Content Export Usage                          1          True
Content Import Usage                          1          True
Definition of usage fields for Education t... 1          True
Definition of usage fields for microblog t... 1          True
Definition of usage fields for service calls  1          True
Definition of usage fields for SPDistribut... 1          True
Definition of usage fields for workflow te... 1          True
Feature Use                                   1          True
File IO                                       1          True
Page Requests                                 1          True
REST and Client API Action Usage              1          True
REST and Client API Request Usage             1          True
Sandbox Request Resource Measures             1          True
Sandbox Requests                              1          True
SQL Exceptions Usage                          1          False
SQL IO Usage                                  1          False
SQL Latency Usage                             1          False
Task Use                                      1          True
Tenant Logging                                1          False
Timer Jobs                                    1          True
Tracks Access Services monitoring usage me... 1          True
Tracks Response Times/Processing Time metr... 1          True
Tracks the CPU and Memory usage characteri... 1          True
Usage Provider for timer job that provides... 1          True
Usage Provider for timer job that provides... 1          True
User Profile ActiveDirectory Import Usage     1          True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a development environment, no I don't see any reason you couldn't shrink it (though you should never shrink databases in production, unless you're going to gain back 40%+ space *and* you need it -- shrinks fragment the indexes).

I would say for your dev environment, you probably want to disable most usage logging, unless you need it for a specific purpose.

Comment: ok thanks ,, but since you mentioned this ,, then why i should not shrink on production ? shrink will remove unused space,, is this correct? so what are the draw backs of it ,, even on production ?

Comment: second question,, now inside my dev machine can i shrink content databases also ? now i shrink WSS_loggin and it freed around 6 gb ..

Answer (score 1):

You can shrink a SharePoint SQL Server database just like any other SQL Server database using SQL Server Management Studio.  This is fine in a development environment, since you are likely the only person using it (might want to give a heads up to the team if there's more than one of you).  Of course, there will be a performance impact on SharePoint itself depending on the size of the database - going from your screenshot above though, I don't think it's going to be big.

Comment: it free around  6GB ..